# {{render}} inside {{#each}} ember.js

Tags: ember.js

So, I have the following template:

```
<h2>Page layout item</h2>
Template name {{templateName}}
{{#each region in regions}}
  {{render "region" regions.firstObject}}
  <div>{{region.id}}</div>
  <div>{{region.height}}</div>
  <div>{{region.width}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

It does not render the regions. I was trying to render out each region using {{render "region" region}} but it wasn't working. However, when I put {{render "region" regions.firstObject}} outside the #each, it works. Regions is a list of objects that were obtained through ember-data via a async hasMany relationship. Any ideas why this is not working or a better way of doing this ?  BTW, the other region. properties render fine.

EDIT:
[This example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kuhifi/10/edit) is analogous to what I was trying to create, thus issue is solved.  Must have been a typo ...

Comment: What does the 'region' template look like? Do the `region`s appear in the ember inspector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`render` helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_render) uses a singleton controller, i.e. you get a single controller for all your regions.
You may want to create a region component or use an [ArrayController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html).

Back to the `render` helper, verify that you are accessing the data correctly, see this jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kivoheqosu/1/edit

Comment: As it turn out though, I don't seem to have a controller for a single region or for the regions list either.  I created controlers 'region' and 'regions' and added test properties to both but I can't access them through {{regions.testProp}} or {{regions.firstObject.testProp}} .  This is because regions is a property of the PageLayout object, which is the only controller I have access to I believe.

Comment: It looks like I need a 'regions' route inside my 'page_layout' resource route

Comment: You're right @givanse [this jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vufure/3/edit?html,css,js), output proves that I should be able to render objects in a loop using render.  Thus it is likely a problem with ember-data and the async hasMany... ?

Comment: I wouldn't point fingers yet. I've updated the answer and your jsbin.

Comment: If you provide an example that actually reproduces the problem that you are having, I'll be able to give you better answers.

Comment: Oh cool, this new bin was helpful in helping me understand some things about controllers i.e. this.set('model.val', 'black'); also works.  Must go back to the drawing board though...